# Woocommerce code chanegs not taking effect

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I am directly editting the woocommerce plugin which I know isn't the correct thing to do but I just want to quickly check if I am looking in the right file.

I have added an extra button to the simple.php add-to-cart file and the button isn't being displayed.

This must be the correct file, could there be something which is preventing the changes from taking effect? I have turned server caching off and changes I made to another plugin took effect straight away.

Here is the button code I added to the file:

```
<button id="preview_product_button" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Preview</button>
```

Comment: if it isn't taking I'd suggest checking out your theme's source and seeing if it is overriding the plugin. This usually found in a woocommerce folder within your theme folder. I'm assuming you added the button around line 48 of simple.php? Let us see your code so we can comment.